# Python 3 module import error from another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Folder Structure:

```
  main
   |__ sub1
      |__ __init__.py
   |__ sub2
      |__ test.py
```

I need to import inside `test.py`:

```
from .. sub1 import SomeClass
```

It shows this error :

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package.

Thank you for responses.

Comment: from which directory are you running `test.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special use case for testing from outside the main source folder. `main` has no reason to be a package, are there could be reasons for not to make it one.

IMHO, the best way is to start tests from the main directory. As the current directory is always in `sys.path`, `sub1` will be directly importable and this would be enough:

```
from sub1 import SomeClass
```

But depending on your dev environment, you may need to launch tests directly from the test directory or any directory other than main. In that case, I am unsure that it is really a best practice, and I only use that for my tests, but a simple trick is to add the parent folder of the test folder to `sys.path`.

Here is what could be the beginning of `test.py`:

```
import os.path
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..")))

from sub1 import SomeClass
...
```

Take it for what it is: a `sys.path` trick that just allows to access the main source folder from the test folder.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `main` nor `sub2` is a package because neither contains a `__init__.py`. See [the relevant Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more information.

Comment: Then how to import a class from this file?

Comment: @Jamshy Try adding `__init__.py` files. They can be empty.